# Is it rude to refer to a person as 古い?

Tags: word-choice, words, politeness

Objects, you can refer to as 古い with impunity. But I have never once heard a person referred to as 古い, so for a long time I thought the word just *didn't apply* to people. Still, searching 古い男 on Google gets pictures of old men. I imagine it's probably best to refer to old people as something like おじいさん or 老人 if their age is relevant, though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To us native speakers, 「古{ふる}い男{おとこ}」 ***does not*** mean "an old man"; It never does to tell the truth.  This is why direct translation could be dangerous at times.

「古い男」 to us generally means "***an old-fashioned man***".  In other words, it is synonymous to 「古いタイプの男」、「価値観{かちかん}の古い男」、「考{かんが}え方{かた}の古い男」, etc.

Therefore, a 「古い男」 does not necessarily have to be biologically old because it is his personal values that matter here.

To refer to "an old man", we use 「年配{ねんぱい}の男の人」、「老人{ろうじん}」、「年老{としお}いた男性{だんせい}」、「おじいさん」, etc.  (We do not use 「男」 by itself nearly as often as you use "man" in English.)

Finally, it might help to remember that 「古い」 is the antonym of 「新{あたら}しい」 ("new") and ***not*** of 「若{わか}い」 ("young").  This is clearly different from English where "old" is the antonym of both "new" and "young".  It is a "well-known" cause of mistranslation.

Comment: From what I have learnt, even though 老人 is commonly used in various (neutral) words and expressions, such as 老人ホーム, to refer to specific individuals as 老人 is considered rude.

Answer (score 11):

> But I have never once heard a person referred to as 古い,

We use 古い also 新しい for a person not for describing his/her age but for describing his/her way/tendency of thinking.

As you know 古い is an adjective, and an adjective has two different ways of use as a predicative use and an attributive one.

An attributive use of 古い is already answered using the example with 古い男, so I'll answer 古い in a predicative use.

古い in 彼は**古い** means 彼の**考え方は古い** *His way of thinking is obsolete/old-fashioned*, while 彼は新しい means *His way of thinking is novel/original/innovative/unconventional/audaciou/avant-garde.*

Both ways of use of 古い could be used, but I think 彼は古い/新しい is used more than 彼は古い男/新しい男です.

## EDIT

A good way to refer to "an old man" is **お年寄｛としよ｝り** like （車内{しゃない}では、）お年寄りに席｛せき｝を譲｛ゆず｝る *to yield one's seat to an elderly person (on the train)*.