# ”ちっとも飛んでない” Meaning in this context

Tags: meaning, japanese-to-english

In Episode 40 of the First Gundam, Amuro and Sayla have this conversation:

> セイラ　「そうよ、アムロはニュータイプですもの」
>
> アムロ　「タイプから言ったら、古い人間らしいけど」
>
> セイラ　「フフ、そうね、おセンチで、ちっとも飛んでないのにね、アムロって」
>
> アムロ　「そう正面きって言われると、いい気分のもんじゃありませんね」

I'm confused by Sayla's second sentence. Is there any slang meaning for tobu that doesn't relate to flying? Can Osenchi in this case also refer to centimeters instead of sentimentality?

Comment: I don’t know the exact story, but it seems that 飛んでる is more or less synonymous to ニュータイプ here (cf. [here](https://www.gundam.info/special-series/native-gundam-remastered/special-series_native-gundam-remastered_20080422_189p.html)). Apparently it means something like *the character is remarkable* or *sticks out* or something along those lines.

Comment: That make sense Sundowner. That he gets a little offended because she says that he doesn't stick out at all. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this 飛んでる/翔んでる is an obsolete buzzword (in 1970's) meaning "freewheeling", "liberal" or "having different sensibilities (than the older generation)". Unlike [ぶっ飛んでる](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%B6%E3%81%A3%E9%A3%9B%E3%81%B6) (which is currently in use in the sense of "outlandish; insane"), 飛んでる was a positive expression.

> #### [飛んでる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%A3%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%82%8B/)
>
> 常識にとらわれずに行動する。自由に生きる。「―◦でる女性」
>
> [補説]「翔んでる」とも書く。

So ちっとも飛んでない means Amuro has a pretty old-fashioned and conservative mindset. 古い人間 refers to this, too (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/57008/5010)). They are jokingly saying he is a [newtype](https://gundam.fandom.com/wiki/Newtype) in one sense but is an "old type" in another sense.

[おセンチ(な)](http://zokugo-dict.com/05o/osenchi.htm) is another buzzword of the 70's meaning "sentimental".

Comment: I assume the underlying metaphor is that jumping (out) = attracting attention? Like the French "sauter aux yeux"?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Those kanji mean *flying* rather than *jumping*. I think flying is a straightforward metaphor for liberation.

Comment: Ah, the "jump" sense is specifically 跳 then?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, 翔 = 飛 = fly, 跳 = jump.